# GPWebpay Webservices in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, module, prestashop

I am currently making a payment module for my client in PHP and I need to connect to WebServices server.

How do I connect to the following endpoint with php SoapClient in wsdl mode?

```
https://test.3dsecure.gpwebpay.com/pay-ws/v1/PaymentService
```

I am lost in options params.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Solved! Here http://osarogabriel.blogspot.cz/2014/03/a-complete-php-soap-client-example.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to download the WSDL file from GpWebPay portal (admin).

```
<?php

$url = 'https://test.3dsecure.gpwebpay.com/pay-ws/v1/PaymentService';


$client = new SoapClient(
    'cws_v1.wsdl',
    array(
        'location' => $url,
        'trace' => 1,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'exceptions' => 0, // Soap vyhodí vlastní chybu s popisem
        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
        'stream_context'=> stream_context_create(array(
                'http' => array(
                    'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
                ),
                'ssl'=> array(
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false, 
                    'allow_self_signed' => true
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

**PHP script for "GP webpay WS API" is here:**

https://zvarik.cz/cs/gp-webpay-ws-api-php [CZECH LANGUAGE]

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer.

Client
http://osarogabriel.blogspot.cz/2014/03/a-complete-php-soap-client-example.html

Server
http://osarogabriel.blogspot.cz/2014/03/a-complete-php-soap-server-example.html